# AngularJS - Disable ng-click if element has specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a list of li items with functions attached to them. I also have an event listener which attaches a class of "current" to whichever li item is being clicked.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="cf" id="filter">
 <li ng-click="getRadius(5)" class="current"><a href="#">5 km</a></li>
 <li ng-click="getRadius(10)"><a href="#">10 km</a></li>
 <li ng-click="getRadius(25)"><a href="#">25 km</a></li>
 <li ng-click="getRadius(50)"><a href="#">50 km</a></li>
 <li ng-click="getRadius(100)"><a href="#">100 km</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to disable the ng-click event if that specific li item has a class of "current" or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: When you assign the `.current` class also set a property on the model and bind on that...?

Comment: I want getRadius functionality???

Comment: @Petrichor Could you give me an example of that? I'm still new to Angular.

Comment: Use a css property `pointer-events: none`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable a list cause its not a interactive element can use ngClass to apply a specific class when disabled to make it appear disabled:

```
<li ng-class="{'disabled':condition}"ng-click="getRadius(5)">item</li>
```

You can use ng-if to remove those items completely from the list:

```
 <li ng-if="!condition" ng-click="getRadius(5)">item</li>
 <li ng-if="condition" >item</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `button` tag as trigger instead of `li`, you can use `ng-disabled` directive to permit click by a condition. For example:

```
<ul class="cf" id="filter">
 <li><button ng-click="getRadius(5)" ng-disabled="current!=5">5 km</button></li>
 <li><button ng-click="getRadius(10)" ng-disabled="current!=10">10 km</button></li>
 <li><button ng-click="getRadius(25)" ng-disabled="current!=25">25 km</button></li>
 <li><button ng-click="getRadius(50)" ng-disabled="current!=50">50 km</button></li>
 <li><button ng-click="getRadius(100)" ng-disabled="current!=100">100 km</button></li>
</ul>
```

If you want, you can customize button style and you can show it like a standart text element.

```
.cf button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// template
<ul class="cf" id="filter">
 <li ng-click="!clickLi[5] && getRadius(5)" class="current"><a href="#">5 km</a></li>
 <li ng-click="!clickLi[10] && getRadius(10)"><a href="#">10 km</a></li>
 <li ng-click="!clickLi[25] && getRadius(25)"><a href="#">25 km</a></li>
 <li ng-click="!clickLi[50] && getRadius(50)"><a href="#">50 km</a></li>
 <li ng-click="!clickLi[100] && getRadius(100)"><a href="#">100 km</a></li>
</ul>    


// controller
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.clickLi = {
        5: true
    };

    $scope.getRadius = function(li_id) {
        $scope.clickLi[li_id] = true;
        console.log(li_id);
    };
}
```

A [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6q99nzn1/) on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround: 
If you need a single selection you can add variable into the scope specifying which row is selected and generate your list with the `ng-repeat`, then you can add lazy checking on `ng-click` if current `$index` is equal to `selected` index, you can use the same condition to apply current class with `ng-class`.

For example:

**app.js**

```
$scope.selected = 0;
$scope.distances = [5, 10, 25, 50, 100];
```

**app.html**

```
<ul class="cf" id="filter">
  <li ng-repeat = "distance in distances" ng-click="($index == selected) || getRadius(distance)" ng-class="{'current':($index == selected)}"><a href="#">{{distance}} km</a></li>
</ul>
```